# How to get bootstrap datepicker input value on day click and copy this value to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a countdown timer and trying to get the **input value to a variable** on bootstrap **datpicker day click**. Can you someone help me to solve it?

Here is the JSfidle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/Devbuddy/qor0jnmw/1/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="span2" value="" id="dp1" >
 <div id="demo">

 </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
            window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
            $('#dp1').datepicker({
                format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
            });
            var dateVal = $('#dp1').val();
        $('.day').on('click', function(){
            $('#demo').text(dateVal);
            });

      var nwdt = "10-06-2017";
        console.log(nwdt);
        var countDownDate = new Date(nwdt).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);



        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the date on when the date is changed:

```
  $('#dp1').on('changeDate', function() {//event for the date change 
    var dateVal = $('#dp1').val();
    nwdt = dateVal;
    countDownDate = new Date(nwdt).getTime();

  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qor0jnmw/3/

Comment: it was custom made for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use datepicker onchange function

```
$('#dp1').change(function() {
        var selected_date=$('#dp1').val();
        alert(selected_date);
        });
```

Use the above code after the below lines in your js fiddle.

```
    $('.day').on('click', function(){
        $('#demo').text(dateVal);
        });
```

and see the alert